# UK Resident marrying Mexican student - Necessary Documents for Camden Council

Tags: united-kingdom, marriage, documentation

I'm British and I wish to marry by Mexican girlfriend, who I have been dating for two years. The first year was a long-distance relationship, but for the last 12 months she has been living in the UK on a Tier 4 Student Visa.

I understand that when applying to marry we need to provide certain documents. The Camden website says the following:

**Proof of address (separate document for each person giving notice)**

- an original (not self-printed) utility bill dated in the last 3 months; or
- an original (not self-printed) bank statement dated in the last 1 month; or
- an original (not self-printed) council tax or mortgage statement dated in the last 12 months; or
- a valid British driving licence (all parts)
- if you don’t live permanently in UK but are setting up residency for at least 7 days especially to give notice, you need proof of your permanent address (see any of above) plus a signed and dated letter from the owner or proprietor of the property where you are staying at which confirms how long you have been staying at their property for and states their name and address

Can anyone explain to me *precisely* what we need to bring with us to the appointment? If, for example, I bring a utility bill in my name, and she brings her bank statements, and they are both original and both correspond to the same address, would that be sufficient? Or is it necessary for us to bring *all* of the above with us?

Many thanks in advance

Link to Camden Website Marriages-section below..

[Camden Council](https://www.camden.gov.uk/ccm/navigation/community-and-living/births--deaths-and-marriages/marriages/?page=9)

Comment: I think you've included the answer to your own question, under proof of address (a separate document for **_each_**) of you. The **_or_** at end of each line means you would bring one, not all, as you describe in your example.

Comment: But there _isn't_ an 'or' after the third item (driving licence), which is why I am wondering if we need to bring e.g. my utility bill, her bank statement _and_ a letter from the landlord, or would just the first two be sufficient?

Comment: Correct: that applies only to her since she is not a permanent resident. You need one proof of residence, she needs two, the bank statement (as you suggest) and the signed and dated letter from the property owner/proprietor where she has been staying which indicates how long she has been at their property and includes the property owner's name and address.

Comment: Of course, as you already know, she needs other documentation regarding her status in the country, passport, visa, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You've understood correctly: under proof of address, it requires a separate document for **each** of you). The **or** at end of each line means you would bring one, not all, as described in your example.

You need one proof of residence. Since she is not a permanent resident, she needs two: the bank statement, as you suggest, and the signed and dated letter from the property owner/proprietor where she has been staying which indicates how long she has been at their property and includes the property owner's name and address.

Of course, as you already know, she needs other documentation regarding her status in the country, passport, visa, etc.

Comment: "Live permanently" and "Permanent residence" are not the same thing. "Live permanently" is about the fact that she lives in the country. Whether legal or illegal, with a visa, as an EU citizen, or with permanent residence. "Permanent residence" is about the right to stay living in the country without having to ask anyone for permission.

Comment: People only need to bring proof of two addresses if they "are setting up residency for at least 7 days especially to give notice." This does not apply to TempyTemp's fiancee.